# Skydrive API using file picker to download file not working

Tags: javascript, api, download, onedrive

I have successfully signed in using JavaScript API and populated my Skydrive files in a separate window. But I can't open Skydrive files to my web application (populate after selected the files then I press open button). Getting following error in error console.

`no element found       ScenarioQos.mvc:1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used old version of wl.js, Now changed wl.js from onedrive.com, So now am download new wl.js replace my workspace after working fine.

**Note : Redirecting url same for workspace js and onedrive account apps redirecting url.**